# React,setInterval,setTimeout,UseEffect,UseState: Why my state does not updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const handleButtonClick = () => {
        if (!active) {
            if (inputValue == '') {
                return
            }
            if (!nodeInGraph(graph, inputValue)) {
                return
            }
        }
        setActive(!active);
    };

 useEffect(() => {
        let itvId;
        if (active) {
            console.log('start')
            const ADJ = RawAdjList(graph);
            setAlgoInfo(pushback(algoInfo,inputValue));
            itvId = setInterval(() => {
                console.log(algoInfo);
                if (algoInfo.arr.length == 0){
                    return () => {
                        clearInterval(itvId);
                        setAlgoInfo(initAlgoInfo());
                    };
                }
                const node = algoInfo.arr[0];
                setAlgoInfo(popback(algoInfo));
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    ADJ[node].array.forEach(n => {
                        if(!algoInfo.path.includes(n)){
                            setAlgoInfo(addPath(algoInfo,n));
                            setAlgoInfo(pushback(algoInfo,n));
                        }
                    });
                },500);
            }, 800);
            
        }
        
        return () => {
            clearInterval(itvId);
            setAlgoInfo(initAlgoInfo());
        };
    }, [active])
/*
graph:{nodes:[],edges:[]}
ADJ:{[key:nodeid]:{[key:nodeid]:weight}
algoInfo:{stack:[],path:[],}

pushback: copy algoinfo and push node in copied algoinfo.stack.
popback: copy algoinfo and pop node in copied algoinfo.stack.
addpath: copy and push node in algoinfo.path
*/
```

When the button is clicked, active becomes true and DFS is executed at regular intervals.
But the algoinfo status is not updated.
When I click the button again, active becomes false and it stopped successfully.
The problem is that the algoinfo is not being infused.
There is also the problem that it keeps repeating even if the stack is empty.
I wonder why.

1. How to terminate DFS when stack is empty?
2. How to update my algoinfo state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` has it's own scope. If you put the `algoInfo` inside `setInterval` and check it's value, it will keep the origin value.

It's recommended, not just for `setInterval`, to call a function inside `setState` to use the previous value and return the new value. Something like this:

```
// use preValue as current value and return a new value
setAlgoInfo(preValue => {
  return addPath(preValue, n)
}
```

It is a little complicated to stop the interval inside itself. I make an easy sample to display what we talk about above. In this sample, I use `useRef` for counting down and stop the interval after the counter value is less than or equal to 0.

https://codesandbox.io/s/interval-scope-v5zpmw?file=/src/App.js

To understand more further, or you may wanna make the component prettier, check this thread, people discuss many valuable contents there:

[Custom Hooks SetInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330186/custom-hooks-setinterval)